# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает код, код не мой, купил приват, кусок предоставлю, ошибка - Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in , работа- то есть появление клиентов не происходит, но сообщение о них есть.

```
VALUES 
('', '$nick', '$bot_group_id', '$email', '$time', '$bot_ip', '$time', 
'$bday', '$bmonth', '$byear', '$time', '$time', '$nick', '$nick', '$nick', '$nick');");
$selectM = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `member_id` AS `id` FROM $p_members WHERE `name`='$nick'"));
if (rand(1,100) <= $bgender_chance) {if (rand(1,100) <= $bgender_male_chance) {$gender = 'm';} else {$gender = 'f';} }
if (rand(1,100) <= $bcity_chance) {$cities = array('Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Новосибирск', 'Екатеринбург', 'Нижний Новгород', 'Самара', 'Омск', 'Казань', 'Челябинск', 'Ростов-на-Дону', 'Уфа', 'Волгоград', 'Пермь', 'Красноярск', 'Воронеж'); $city = $cities[rand(1,15)];}
if (rand(1,100) <= $bicq_chance) {$icq = rand(1000000,999999999);}
if (rand(1,100) <= $bsign_chance) { 
if (rand(1,100) <= $bsign_usebar_chance) {$bsign_usebar_id = rand(1,50);$bsign_usebar = '[url=http://imagger.ru][img]http://imagger.ru/imgs/usebars/'.$bsign_usebar_id.'.jpg[/img][/url]';}
$addinfo = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $p_profile_portal (`pp_member_id`, `signature`) VALUES ('$selectM[id]', '$bsign_usebar')"); }
$adddata = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $p_pfields_content (`member_id`, `field_4`, `field_5`, `field_6`, `field_3`) VALUES ('$selectM[id]', '$icq', '$gender', '$city', 'http://okda.ru')");
$selectT = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `tid` AS `id` FROM $p_topics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
if (rand(1,100) <= $rtheme_chance) {$rtheme = $selectT[id];} else {$rtheme = '0';}
if ($rtheme_allow == yes) {$upd[views] = mysql_query("UPDATE $p_topics SET `views`=`views`+'1' WHERE (`tid`='$rtheme')");}
$addtoloa = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $p_sessions (`id`, `member_name`, `seo_name`, `member_id`, `ip_address`, `browser`,
`running_time`, `member_group`, `location_1_type`, `location_1_id`, `current_appcomponent`, `current_module`, 
`uagent_key`, `uagent_version`, `uagent_type`, `current_section`, `location_2_type`)
VALUES ('$hash', '$nick', '$nick', '$selectM[id]', '$bot_ip', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0', 
'$time', '$bot_group_id', 'topic', '$rtheme', 'forums', 'forums', 'firefox', '6', 'browser', 'topics', 'forum')");
echo ''.$nick.' ('.$email.') - ONLINE<br>';
$result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error());
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У тебя команда `mysql_query()` возвращает false что указывает на то что либо во время запроса

```
mysql_query("SELECT `member_id` AS `id` FROM $p_members WHERE
   `name`='$nick'")
```

либо в этом запросе

```
mysql_query("SELECT `tid` AS `id` FROM $p_topics ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1")
```

происходит ошибка.

Для выявление проблемы необходимо сразу не передовать результат `mysql_query()` в `mysql_fetch_array()`. А перед этим проверить вернул ли `mysql_query()` ресурс а потом уже передавать его `mysql_fetch_array()`.

То есть ты для дебага можешь сделать что-то на подобии этого.
Для первого запроса.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `tid` AS `id` FROM $p_topics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
if( !is_resource($result) ) {
    exit('MySql first query error: ' . mysql_error());
}
$selectT = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

И для второго запроса.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `member_id` AS `id` FROM $p_members WHERE `name`='$nick'");
if( !is_resource($result) ) {
    exit('MySql second query error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$selectM = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```